# Mysql sub select with SUM() and group by

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to create a query that does a calculation in a subquery that requires the SUM function and a group by. My query returns the error "Subquery returns more than 1 row". Essentially I am trying to return the amount "Due" for each order. If the order total is greater than the sum of total_collected (for that order_id) from the payments table there will be amount due. Here is the query:

```
SELECT o.order_id
     , o.server
     , o.subtotal
     , o.discount
     , o.tax, o.total
     , (SELECT (o.total - SUM(p.total_collected)) 
            from orders o 
            join payments p 
              on o.order_id = p.order_id 
        group by p.order_id) as 'Due'
  FROM orders o 
  join payments p 
    on o.order_id = p.order_id
WHERE...;
```

I cannot include 'p.order_id' in the sub select because it should only contain one column. I understand why I am getting the error, I just don't know how to get the sub select to only perform the SUM on a per order_id basis.

Comment: Can you include your expected output?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing the structure much, I think the subquery is looking at all of the data in the orders/payments tables. I think you need to filter it down to look only at the relevant order_id like so.

(I also added a SUM around the order total because I am pretty sure that would give a different error without it.)

```
SELECT o.order_id
     , o.server
     , o.subtotal
     , o.discount
     , o.tax
     , o.total
     , (SELECT (SUM(o2.total) - SUM(p.total_collected))
            from orders o2 
            JOIN payments p 
              ON o2.order_id = p.order_id
            WHERE o2.order_id = o.order_id) as 'Due'
    FROM orders o
WHERE...;
```

Although, if you adjust this so that it uses a join instead of a subquery, I think you will get better performance. Something like this:

```
SELECT o.order_id
     , o.server
     , o.subtotal
     , o.discount
     , o.tax
     , o.total
     , o.total - c.Collected AS 'Due'
    FROM orders o
    JOIN (
        SELECT p2.order_id, SUM(p2.total_collected) AS 'Collected'
          FROM payments p2
        GROUP BY p2.order_id) AS c
      ON o.order_id = c.order_id
WHERE...;
```

Comment: There is no need for a join in the subquery.

Comment: Using the sub select in the JOIN in your 2nd example worked great! Thank you David!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need sub-query:

```
SELECT
  o.order_id,
  o.server,
  o.subtotal,
  o.discount,
  o.tax,
  o.total,
  o.total - ifnull(sum(p.total_collected),0) As Due
FROM orders AS o 
LEFT JOIN payments AS p ON o.order_id = p.order_id
WHERE ...
GROUP BY o.order_id
```